# How to get MethodInfo of a generic method on a non generic .NET type?

Tags: .net, reflection, methodinfo, generic-method

I have this little problem, that I cannot figure out which arguments to pass to Type.GetMethod in order to get back the MethodInfo of a generic method on a non generic type.
Specifically, I have this type definition:

```
public static class A
{
  public static B F<T>(bool dummy)
  {
  }
  public static B F<T>(IEnumerable<T> arg)
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

I have tried several takes at Type.GetMethod, but none would return the MethodInfo of the F method.

I am aware that I can invoke Type.GetMethods or even Type.FindMember, but I am interested in Type.GetMethod.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Actually, my code is a bit more complex. The generic method is overloaded, so I cannot use the Type.GetMethod with just the function name.
I tried these variants:

```
typeof(A).GetMethod("F", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[]{ typeof(IEnumerable<>) }, null)
typeof(A).GetMethod("F`1", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[]{ typeof(IEnumerable<>) }, null)
typeof(A).GetMethod("F[T]", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[]{ typeof(IEnumerable<>) }, null)
typeof(A).GetMethod("F[[T]]", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[]{ typeof(IEnumerable<>) }, null)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the `IEnumerable<>` parameter you are passing to `GetMethod` is not specialized.  It really is an `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is specified by the method you are trying to retrieve.  But, we can't get `T` via `MethodInfo.GetGenericArguments()` since we don't have a reference to the method -- we are still trying to retrieve it.

Unfortunately, this is where the reflection API falls short.  There is no `Type.GetMethod()` overload that allows you to distinguish between overloaded methods, where one is a generic method.

So with that said, you are stuck using `Type.GetMethods()` and filtering the results with a predicate of your choice.  To get the method you are interested in, you can do the following.

```
void getMethod()
{
    typeof(A).GetMethods().Where(m =>
        m.IsGenericMethod &&
        m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
            == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
}
```

N.B.  I haven't verified that the `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` call is required; you may be able to omit it.  The idea is that you are transforming a type `A<T>` into `A<>`, but the runtime may already give it to you in that form.

Answer (score 5):

**(Updated in response to question clarifications):**

There is no way to get a handle to the method using `GetMethod` (eg. one line), because the generic data to define the method isn't available until we have the method to inspect.

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(A).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
MethodInfo genericMethod = methods.Where(m=>m.IsGenericMethod).First(m=>m.ContainsGenericParameters);
genericMethod = genericMethod.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

1. Get the methods
2. Find the method that has generic parameters (assuming you only have one - if you add more than one, this needs to be a little more robust)
3. Get the generic methodinfo

Comment: Thanks, but I have slighly misled in the question. I have changed it to be more accurate.

Comment: Thank you, but as I mention in my question I do know how to do it with GetMethods or FindMember. I am specifically interested in GetMethod, because it should do the job as well, but it does not and that bothers me.

Comment: @Mark there is no way to do it, because the generic data to define the method isn't available until we have the method to inspect.